# Borrowing pointers in a safe way

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm working on some library and would like to define private utility header `util.h` with the following type:

```
/**
* The struct is used to indicate that deallocation function 
* for some object containing the struct util_borrowed_ptr
* as a subobject should not reclaim memory borrowed_ptr points to
*/
struct util_borrowed_ptr{
    void *ptr;
};
```

This is sort of a "marker type" to provide some info for the client. Otherwise it is not clear whether memory should or should not be deallocated. Currently I have the following use case:

```
struct some_data{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct lib_context{
    struct some_data *sd_ptr;
};

struct service{
    struct util_borrowed_ptr some_data_ptr;
};

struct service * create_from_context(struct lib_context *ctx_ptr){
    struct service *svc = malloc(sizeof *svc);
    struct util_borrowed_ptr some_data_ptr = {
        .ptr = ctx_ptr -> sd_ptr
    };
    svc -> some_data_ptr = some_data_ptr;
    return svc;
}

void release_service(struct service *svc){
    free(svc); //we do not reclaim memory
               //pointed to by borrowed_ptr
}
```

In this case it is clear for the client of `struct service` that its field does not have to be deallocated since it was borrowed from somewhere.

The problem is it has type `void *` so I have to cast it back and forth to  `struct some_data *` which is extremely error-prone.

Does such "borrowed pointer" ever make sense? If so how I would do it type safer (if possible)

Comment: This seems rather open-ended and opinion-based.

Comment: @JohnBollinger This idea came when I tried to formalize some contract for allocation/deallocation of objects I use across the library....

Comment: However, my first inclination is to say no, such a thing does not make sense in C.  It seems like an attempt to map a C++ approach onto C, but idiomatic C does not put anything like the same emphasis on type determining use as C++ does.  In C, it is more typical to rely on functions to do what they are specified to do, and to to rely on programmers not to ask for something they don't want done.

Comment: Since you control the `service` structure API, including the creation and release, why bother with the `util_borrowed_ptr` at all? Document that all creation of the `service` structure must by done by `create_from_context`, and that all releasing of the structure must be done via the `release_service` function, and have a proper pointer to `struct some_data` inside the `service` structure. If the user does something they aren't supposed to do, then the problem is their own.

Comment: C doesn't have overloading or generics/templates or runtime type checks. The only use `util_borrowed_ptr` would have is some sort of documentation for the application programmer: They're not supposed to write code that frees `util_borrowed_ptr` manually (but they totally could). Since the only use of this type is to provide a hint to human users of the interface, why try to make it generic? Why not define different wrapper structs for different pointer types (if you have to do it at all)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This sounds reasonable. I can think of the following policy: explicitly document allocation/deallocation when it requires some special handling. Unless documented the assumption is to deallocate everything.

Comment: More generally, @St.Antario, my policy is that all pointer exchanges across function boundaries document whether ownership of the pointer value is transferred.  The (current) owner is responsible for freeing the pointer or transferring ownership before it goes out of scope.  Non-owners are responsible for *avoiding* freeing the pointer or doing anything with it that would require them to transfer ownership.